# Branch.io retrieving BranchUniversalObject on first run after installation on Android

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I am using Branch.io for deep linking. If the app is already installed, everything works fine, but if this is the first run after installation of the app then the following code is never executed (inside onStart)

```
Branch branch = Branch.getAutoInstance(getApplicationContext());
branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchUniversalReferralInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitFinished(BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject,
                    LinkProperties linkProperties, BranchError branchError) {
        DeepLinkUtil.processBranchIntent(branchUniversalObject);
    }
});
```

I am not installing from the PlayStore, but downloading from a server. When I click on the link, the download starts in the browser and then I can click on the downloaded APK to install it. After installation, when the APK is opened for the first time, the above code is never executed.

I've added the following code in the onStart():

```
Branch branch = Branch.getAutoInstance(getApplicationContext());
JSONObject installParams = branch.getFirstReferringParams();
if (installParams == null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "processIntent: installParams: null");
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "processIntent: installParams: " + installParams.toString());
}
```

When running for the first time after install, install params are NOT null, but are empty - {}. When running for the 2nd time, install params contains the correct information from the link that was clicked, but 'is_first_session' is now false.

I do have install referrer receiver registered in the manifest, but I am not clear if it works for PlayStore only installs or any installs.

What else do I need to do to get the referral link on the first run after installation?

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io here:

Couple things to talk about.

1. The [`getFirstReferringParams`](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking#retrieve-install-install-only-parameters) method doesn't do quite what you're expecting.  It returns data on the link that caused the *first install on that device*, so if that install wasn't referred from a Branch link, the return will be empty by design. Note that this is the first install **ever** on that device, so those values will not change even between installs. See the [debug mode](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/integration-testing/guide/android/#use-debug-mode-to-simulate-fresh-installs) if you want this to behave differently for testing purposes.
2. I suspect you may have accidentally merged the Branch snippets from the `onStart()` method in your `Activity` and the `onStart()` method in your custom Application class. If so, it might help to review the [SDK integration guide](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/).

Comment: not sure what you mean in your #2. Everything I've posted in my question is from the Activity's onStart(). In the Application's onCreate() I have Branch.getAutoInstance() and Branch.enablePlayStoreReferrer().

Comment: That's likely the issue then — you have some code (specifically `Branch.getAutoInstance`) that shouldn't be in the Activity at all. I'd suggest going back through the integration instructions to make sure everything is according to plan.

Comment: you are right, I've confused the Branch.getAutoInstance() and Branch.getInstance() - not the best choice of names :) Not sure if this is the root of the problem, need to experiment more.

Comment: Feel free to [reach out to the Branch Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) if you would like a hand debugging!